# Python docker image not smaller when using wheels and multi-stage

Tags: python, docker, pip, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm trying to reduce the size of my docker image by using pip wheels and docker multi-stage (following mainly [this](https://www.peterspython.com/en/blog/reducing-the-size-of-a-python-application-docker-image-using-python-wheels)) but after numerous attempts, my final image is larger than what it using to be.

Here is my docker file

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########
FROM python:3.8-buster as builder

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# pip install
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip wheel --wheel-dir=/usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt


#########
# FINAL #
#########
FROM python:3.8-buster

ENV APP_HOME=/usr/src/app
RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install latest updates (mainly for security updates)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

# install dependencies from builder image
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-index --find-links=/wheels -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . .
```

When looking at the image layers with dive, I can see that the layer generated with `RUN /bin/sh -c pip install --no-index --find-links=/wheels -r requirements.txt` has the same size that what it is without wheels (eg 323 MB). It looks like the pip wheels step in the builder phase had no impact on the final image and everything had to be rebuilt again. The reason my image is bigger is because of the 78MB from the wheels step `COPY /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels # buildkit`
[image: Docker image layers]

Here are the logs of this layer

```
#17 sha256:27b636969dce3a5e62ace532236d71a874b02a69af7e03dbecbf425e347f0f2f
#17 1.763 Looking in links: /wheels
#17 1.786 Processing /wheels/amqp-5.0.6-py3-none-any.whl
#17 1.804 Processing /wheels/asgiref-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
#17 1.820 Processing /wheels/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 1.835 Processing /wheels/click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 1.850 Processing /wheels/click_log-0.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 1.868 Processing /wheels/Django-3.2.6-py3-none-any.whl
#17 1.926 Processing /wheels/djangorestframework-3.12.2-py3-none-any.whl
#17 1.949 Processing /wheels/gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
#17 1.972 Processing /wheels/numpy-1.21.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
#17 1.997 Processing /wheels/psycopg2-2.9.1-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
#17 2.015 Processing /wheels/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.039 Processing /wheels/requests-2.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.062 Processing /wheels/scipy-1.7.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl
#17 2.097 Processing /wheels/Shapely-1.7.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
#17 2.119 Processing /wheels/sympy-1.8-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.163 Processing /wheels/XlsxWriter-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.184 Processing /wheels/PyYAML-5.4.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
#17 2.206 Processing /wheels/uritemplate-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.230 Processing /wheels/django_cors_headers-3.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.250 Processing /wheels/djangorestframework_simplejwt-4.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.270 Processing /wheels/PyJWT-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.295 Processing /wheels/celery-5.1.2-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.314 Processing /wheels/redis-3.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.335 Processing /wheels/flower-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.358 Processing /wheels/locust-2.5.1-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.381 Processing /wheels/vine-5.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.422 Processing /wheels/pytz-2021.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.448 Processing /wheels/sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.465 Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gunicorn==20.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8)) (57.5.0)
#17 2.493 Processing /wheels/six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.532 Processing /wheels/idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.559 Processing /wheels/certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.582 Processing /wheels/charset_normalizer-2.0.12-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.607 Processing /wheels/urllib3-1.26.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.662 Processing /wheels/mpmath-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.837 Processing /wheels/click_didyoumean-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.855 Processing /wheels/click_repl-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.872 Processing /wheels/click_plugins-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.890 Processing /wheels/kombu-5.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.906 Processing /wheels/billiard-3.6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.944 Processing /wheels/prometheus_client-0.13.1-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.962 Processing /wheels/humanize-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
#17 2.978 Processing /wheels/tornado-6.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
#17 3.009 Processing /wheels/ConfigArgParse-1.5.3-py3-none-any.whl
#17 3.026 Processing /wheels/msgpack-1.0.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
#17 3.045 Processing /wheels/Flask_Cors-3.0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 3.062 Processing /wheels/geventhttpclient-1.5.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
#17 3.082 Processing /wheels/typing_extensions-4.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
#17 3.102 Processing /wheels/pyzmq-22.3.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
#17 3.124 Processing /wheels/psutil-5.9.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
#17 3.145 Processing /wheels/Flask-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
#17 3.163 Processing /wheels/Flask_BasicAuth-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
#17 3.183 Processing /wheels/roundrobin-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
#17 3.202 Processing /wheels/gevent-21.12.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
#17 3.225 Processing /wheels/Werkzeug-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
#17 3.359 Processing /wheels/prompt_toolkit-3.0.28-py3-none-any.whl
#17 3.428 Processing /wheels/itsdangerous-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
#17 3.448 Processing /wheels/Jinja2-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
#17 3.544 Processing /wheels/zope.event-4.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 3.561 Processing /wheels/greenlet-1.1.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
#17 3.577 Processing /wheels/zope.interface-5.4.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
#17 3.605 Processing /wheels/Brotli-1.0.9-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
#17 3.885 Processing /wheels/MarkupSafe-2.1.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
#17 3.920 Processing /wheels/wcwidth-0.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
#17 4.815 Installing collected packages: wcwidth, Shapely, roundrobin, pytz, msgpack, mpmath, chardet, certifi, brotli, billiard, zope.interface, zope.event, XlsxWriter, Werkzeug, vine, urllib3, uritemplate, typing-extensions, tornado, sympy, sqlparse, six, redis, pyzmq, pyyaml, PyJWT, psycopg2, psutil, prompt-toolkit, prometheus-client, numpy, MarkupSafe, itsdangerous, idna, humanize, gunicorn, greenlet, ConfigArgParse, click, charset-normalizer, asgiref, scipy, requests, python-dateutil, Jinja2, gevent, Django, click-repl, click-plugins, click-log, click-didyoumean, amqp, kombu, geventhttpclient, flask, djangorestframework, django-cors-headers, Flask-Cors, Flask-BasicAuth, djangorestframework_simplejwt, celery, locust, flower
#17 39.16 Successfully installed ConfigArgParse-1.5.3 Django-3.2.6 Flask-BasicAuth-0.2.0 Flask-Cors-3.0.10 Jinja2-3.0.3 MarkupSafe-2.1.0 PyJWT-2.1.0 Shapely-1.7.1 Werkzeug-2.0.3 XlsxWriter-3.0.3 amqp-5.0.6 asgiref-3.4.1 billiard-3.6.4.0 brotli-1.0.9 celery-5.1.2 certifi-2021.10.8 chardet-3.0.4 charset-normalizer-2.0.12 click-7.1.2 click-didyoumean-0.3.0 click-log-0.3.2 click-plugins-1.1.1 click-repl-0.2.0 django-cors-headers-3.8.0 djangorestframework-3.12.2 djangorestframework_simplejwt-4.8.0 flask-2.0.3 flower-1.0.0 gevent-21.12.0 geventhttpclient-1.5.3 greenlet-1.1.2 gunicorn-20.1.0 humanize-4.0.0 idna-3.3 itsdangerous-2.1.1 kombu-5.2.2 locust-2.5.1 mpmath-1.2.1 msgpack-1.0.3 numpy-1.21.2 prometheus-client-0.13.1 prompt-toolkit-3.0.28 psutil-5.9.0 psycopg2-2.9.1 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2021.3 pyyaml-5.4.1 pyzmq-22.3.0 redis-3.5.3 requests-2.27.1 roundrobin-0.0.2 scipy-1.7.1 six-1.16.0 sqlparse-0.4.2 sympy-1.8 tornado-6.1 typing-extensions-4.1.1 uritemplate-3.0.1 urllib3-1.26.8 vine-5.0.0 wcwidth-0.2.5 zope.event-4.5.0 zope.interface-5.4.0
```

Is there somthing I'm missing ? Why is there no benefit from pre packaging the install with wheels ?